# Why my request works in python but not with curl

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, http-headers, http-status-code-403

Hi i try fetch from this [url](https://dooood.com/d/h9rojbkqnpan) with curl and i got 403 error but it perfectly work in python with request

python code

```
import requests

headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36 OPR/67.0.3575.97',
        'Referer': 'https://dooood.com/'}
url = "https://dooood.com/d/h9rojbkqnpan"
res = requests.get('https://dooood.com/d/h9rojbkqnpan', headers=headers)
print(res.content)
print(res.status_code)
```

curl command

```
 curl -I "https://dooood.com/d/h9rojbkqnpan" \
  -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36 OPR/67.0.3575.97" \
  -H "Referer: https://dooood.com/"
```

is python requests add extra headers ?

Comment: Please inspect (and include) the contents of `res.request.headers` vs. the output of `curl -v` instead (i.e. include the `-v` flag) so the actual full set of headers sent can then be properly compared.

Comment: @metatoaster yes requests in python add some others headers 
now it is good thanks

Comment: Would be useful to include these additional details into the question, and perhaps add in a self-answer documenting the differences of headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

requests in python add some headers

```
import requests

headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36 OPR/67.0.3575.97',
        'Referer': 'https://dooood.com/'}
url = "https://dooood.com/d/h9rojbkqnpan"
res = requests.get('https://dooood.com/d/h9rojbkqnpan', headers=headers)
print(res.content)
print(res.status_code)
#display all headers
print(res.request.headers)
```

my final curl command

```
curl -X GET "https://dooood.com/d/h9rojbkqnpan" \
  -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36 OPR/67.0.3575.97" \
  -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" \
  -H "Accept: */*" \
  -H "Connection: keep-alive" \
  -H "Referer: https://dooood.com/" \
   --compressed -i -v
```